# Problem with installing web3 on ubuntu 18.04 using npm

Tags: web3js, npm

I am trying to install web3 on my ubuntu 18.04 system. I am using the following command:

@lc2530hz:~$ sudo npm install -g web3

but I am getting the error:

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

But when I am typing: @lc2530hz:~$ npm --version 6.14.6

Kindly guide me how to install web3.

## Zulfi.

I am getting same response when I try without 'g' switch

```
@lc2530hz:~$ sudo npm install web3
[sudo] password for zulfi: 
sudo: npm: command not found


@lc2530hz:~$ npm --version
6.14.6
@lc2530hz:~$
```

Hi,
I did "pip install web3"

I got following message at the end:

Successfully built bitarray pyrsistent cytoolz
Installing collected packages: hexbytes, certifi, idna, urllib3, chardet, requests, pycryptodome, eth-hash, toolz, cytoolz, eth-typing, eth-utils, six, parsimonious, eth-abi, bitarray, eth-keys, eth-keyfile, rlp, eth-rlp, eth-account, websockets, base58, zipp, importlib-resources, netaddr, varint, multiaddr, ipfshttpclient, lru-dict, pyrsistent, typing-extensions, importlib-metadata, attrs, setuptools, jsonschema, protobuf, web3
Successfully installed attrs-20.3.0 base58-2.0.1 bitarray-1.2.2 certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-4.0.0 cytoolz-0.11.0 eth-abi-2.1.1 eth-account-0.5.4 eth-hash-0.2.0 eth-keyfile-0.5.1 eth-keys-0.3.3 eth-rlp-0.2.1 eth-typing-2.2.2 eth-utils-1.9.5 hexbytes-0.2.1 idna-2.10 importlib-metadata-3.3.0 importlib-resources-3.3.0 ipfshttpclient-0.7.0a1 jsonschema-3.2.0 lru-dict-1.1.6 multiaddr-0.0.9 netaddr-0.8.0 parsimonious-0.8.1 protobuf-3.14.0 pycryptodome-3.9.9 pyrsistent-0.17.3 requests-2.25.1 rlp-2.0.1 setuptools-51.1.0.post20201221 six-1.15.0 toolz-0.11.1 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 urllib3-1.26.2 varint-1.0.2 web3-5.13.1 websockets-8.1 zipp-3.4.0

But when I am doing:

> @lc2530hz:~$ web3
>
> Command 'web3' not found, did you mean:
>
> command 'deb3' from deb quilt
>
> Try: sudo apt install

==
Hi,
When I did:

$ npm install -g web3

I got following output:

```
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: stable api reached

> bufferutil@4.0.2 install /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp-build


> keccak@3.0.1 install /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/keccak
> node-gyp-build || exit 0


> secp256k1@4.0.2 install /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/secp256k1
> node-gyp-build || exit 0


> utf-8-validate@5.0.3 install /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp-build

+ web3@1.3.1
added 352 packages from 328 contributors in 30.44s
```

But when  I did:

zulfi@lc2530hz:~$ web3

Command 'web3' not found, did you mean:

command 'deb3' from deb quilt

Try: sudo apt install

==installing without 'g'
$ npm install web3
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: stable api reached

> bufferutil@4.0.2 install /home/zulfi/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp-build

> keccak@3.0.1 install /home/zulfi/node_modules/keccak
> node-gyp-build || exit 0

> secp256k1@4.0.2 install /home/zulfi/node_modules/secp256k1
> node-gyp-build || exit 0

> utf-8-validate@5.0.3 install /home/zulfi/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp-build

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/zulfi/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/zulfi/package.json'
npm WARN zulfi No description
npm WARN zulfi No repository field.
npm WARN zulfi No README data
npm WARN zulfi No license field.

- web3@1.3.1
  added 349 packages from 325 contributors and audited 354 packages in 18.391s

41 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
zulfi@lc2530hz:~$ npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zulfi/.npm/_logs/2020-12-21T23_36_40_266Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install web3, without "-g", just npm install web3 ([like the package states](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3))

-g is used to have the command available in all directories, but you will only need web3 in your client javascript project.

**EDIT 1:**
You can try adding the web3 script from a CDN like this: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/web3

**EDIT 2:**

To solve your npm problem in Ubuntu, try this (but is an OS issue, not web3):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Comment: My friend I am getting the same response. Still not able to install web3.

Comment: You can try to add the web3 script from a CDN like this: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/web3

Comment: Hi, I used "pip install web3'. It sows several packages installed, see above. But when I am doing "$web3", it says command not found. Kindly guide me whether I installed web3 or not.

Comment: Hi, when I used "npm install web3", I got the following message: found 1 low severity vulnerability. I have added all the details above. Please guide me.